# SpringCloud application Docker image failed to start

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have 2 Spring cloud applications. First application is pointing to externalized git properties
used @EnableConfigServer. Dockerised that and running.

### Spring cloud config server application.properties:

```
server.port=9090
#spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///${user.home}/MicroService/centralProperties/
#spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations=file:///C:/PERSONAL/JAVA_PERSONAL_WORKSPACE/SpringWorkSpace2018/MicroserviceConfigServer/MicroService/centralProperties
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/myRepo/SpringCloudConfigProperties.git
#SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=native

#Verify any repository issue in service startup
spring.cloud.config.server.git.cloneOnStart=true
 
#Disable security of the Management end point
management.security.enabled=false
```

Dockerfile :

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="santanuguha2006@gmail.com"

# Add the application's jar to the container
COPY target/spring-cloud-config-server.jar /opt/spring-cloud-config-server/

WORKDIR /opt/spring-cloud-config-server/

#RUN mvn package

#VOLUME /config-files

#WORKDIR /
# Make port 8085 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 9090
# Run the jar file
#ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","*******.jar"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar",\
            "/opt/spring-cloud-config-server/spring-cloud-config-server.jar",\
            "--server.port=9090",\
            "--spring.config.name=spring-cloud-config-server"]
```

**The second application has the below bootstrap.yml config :**

```
server:
  port: 8787
spring:
  application:
    name: CloudClient
  cloud:
    config:
      uri: http://localhost:9090
```

Second application Dockerfile:

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM openjdk:8

# Add Maintainer Info
LABEL maintainer="santanuguha2006@gmail.com"

# Add the application's jar to the container
COPY target/CloudConfig-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/spring-cloud-config-api/

WORKDIR /opt/spring-cloud-config-api/

#RUN mvn package

#VOLUME /config-files

#WORKDIR /
# Make port 8787 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8787
# Run the jar file
#ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","*******.jar"]
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom", "-jar",\
            "/opt/spring-cloud-config-api/CloudConfig-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar",\
            "--server.port=8787",\
            "--spring.config.name=spring-cloud-config-api"]
```

Second application is not being able to access the externalized properties using @Value in Spring from Docker. But as a normal Springboot application second one can access @Value . What wrong I am doing can anyone help?

error while starting second application docker as follows :
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.cloudControllerPropertiesFetch': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'spring.datasource.url' in value "${spring.datasource.url}"